# Rails select field is not showing currect values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create the object the values appear correct inside the db; however, when I try to edit the values the select tag values they appear wrong.

I have a different form for edit:

```
<%= form_for(@opening_hour, url: store_opening_hours_update_path) do |form| %>



  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.select :day, [['Select a day'], ['Monday', 1], ['Tuesday', 2], ['Wednesday', 3],
                         ['Thursday', 4], ['Friday', 5], ['Saturday', 6],['Sunday', 7]], {}, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.select :opens, [['Select opening hour'],['12:00', 12], ['13:00', 13], ['14:00', 14], ['15:00', 15], ['16:00', 16], ['17:00', 17],
                           ['18:00', 18], ['19:00', 19], ['20:00', 20], ['21:00', 21], ['22:00', 22], ['23:00', 23], ['24:00', 24],
                           ['01:00', 1], ['02:00', 2], ['03:00', 3], ['04:00', 4], ['05:00', 5], ['06:00', 6], ['07:00', 7],
                           ['08:00', 8], ['09:00', 9], ['10:00', 10], ['11:00', 11]], {}, class: "form-control"  %>
  </div>
```

In the controller:

```
def edit
  @opening_hour = OpeningHour.find(params[:id])
end
```

Once I edit and reopen the edit form, the values appear correct.
Any idea why this is happening?

**Update 1**

```
before_action :set_opening_hour, only: [:edit, :update]

def create
  @opening_hour = OpeningHour.create(opening_hour_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @opening_hour.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_opening_hours_index_path and return}
        flash[:notice] = "Hours were successfully created."
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @opening_hour.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @opening_hour.update(opening_hour_params)
      format.html { redirect_to store_opening_hours_index_path and return}
      flash[:notice] = "Hours were successfully updated."
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @opening_hour.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def set_opening_hour
  @opening_hour = OpeningHour.find(params[:id])
end

def opening_hour_params
  params.require(:opening_hour).permit(:user_id, :day, :closes, :opens, :valid_from, :valid_through)
end
end
```

edit form:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_for(@opening_hour, url: store_opening_hours_update_path) do |form| %>
    <% if @opening_hour.errors.any? %>
      <div class="centerList">
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@opening_hour.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited the business hours from being saved:</h2>
        <% @opening_hour.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  <% end %>


  <div class="form-group">
   <%= form.select :day, [['Select a day'], ['Monday', 1], ['Tuesday', 2], ['Wednesday', 3],
                          ['Thursday', 4], ['Friday', 5], ['Saturday', 6],['Sunday', 7]], {}, class: "form-control" %>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.select :opens, [['Select opening hour'],['12:00', '12:00'], ['13:00', 13], ['14:00', 14], ['15:00', 15], ['16:00', 16], ['17:00', 17],
                           ['18:00', 18], ['19:00', 19], ['20:00', 20], ['21:00', 21], ['22:00', 22], ['23:00', 23], ['24:00', 24],
                           ['01:00', 1], ['02:00', 2], ['03:00', 3], ['04:00', 4], ['05:00', 5], ['06:00', 6], ['07:00', 7],
                           ['08:00', 8], ['09:00', 9], ['10:00', 10], ['11:00', '11:00']], {}, class: "form-control"  %>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.select :closes, [['Select closing hour'],['12:00', 12], ['13:00', 13], ['14:00', '14:00'], ['15:00', 15], ['16:00', 16], ['17:00', '17:00'],
                           ['18:00', 18], ['19:00', 19], ['20:00', 20], ['21:00', 21], ['22:00', 22], ['23:00', 23], ['24:00', 24],
                           ['01:00', 1], ['02:00', 2], ['03:00', 3], ['04:00', 4], ['05:00', 5], ['06:00', 6], ['07:00', 7],
                           ['08:00', 8], ['09:00', 9], ['10:00', 10], ['11:00', '11:00']], {}, class: "form-control"  %>
</div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.submit t("opening_hours_index_6"), :class=>"btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div id="fixed-bottom-spacing" style="height: 60px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: If `edit` and `update` is working but `new` and `create` isn't, I would suspect the problem is in your `create` method. Can you include that method in your question?

Comment: Agreed with @SteveTurczyn, the issue on create method

Comment: Thanks for the replies @ SteveTurczyn and @fool dev... I can create, edit and update all just fine... the issue is when I open the edit form for the first time the select tag` opens` appears with the wrong values inside! I also failed to mention in my question that the `opens` columns is being saved as  
`t.time "opens"` and thus returning a  value of `Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:00:00 UTC +00:00` for my 12:00 value

Comment: When you say "open the edit form for the first time" you mean after your first create, or you mean when you're creating a new `OpeningHour`  ?  `edit` form in rails is only for editing existing records, 'new` form in rails is for a new record.  Please (also) be more specific about what "appears wrong" means.

Comment: Ahd, please show your create and update methods. Please!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn i just updated my question with the create and update method!

Comment: Great, thanks, and I see you say "I have a different form for edit".  Can you show the `new` form?

Comment: @ SteveTurczyn I just did!!

Comment: I only see the `edit` form, I was asking for the `new` form

Answer (score 0):

Just try as:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= form.select :day, [['Select a day'], ['Monday', 1], ['Tuesday', 2], ['Wednesday', 3],['Thursday', 4], ['Friday', 5], ['Saturday', 6],['Sunday', 7]],  class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

2nd bracket is problem.

Comment: That's a value for `options`, with the class appearing in `html_options`. Without the empty hash this wouldn't work. [Docs here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the problem to be that when you edit the record the correct value for 'opens' is not selected in the dropdown.

This is being caused by a mismatch between the value provided in the select and the value in the database.

You are restoring a time from the database and trying to match this to an integer value in the dropdown. 
For instance ['12:00', 12] will store the value **12** into the database and expect **12** to be returned. 
As the column is a time datatype when you edit the record the value returned is not 12 as is required by the dropdown option.

You will need to either change the database column type or change the value in the dropdown option. The choice will depend upon your business case.